# What am I missing when solving this integral with trigonometric substition?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

**The integral**

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dx$$

---

**What I've tried**

I've tried doing the substitution with

$$x^2=9\sin^2\theta$$
$$x=3\sin\theta$$
$$dx=3\cos\theta$$

my solving...

$$=\int\frac{27\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{9-9\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$
$$=27\int\frac{\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{9(1-\sin^2\theta)}}d\theta$$
$$=9\int\frac{\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}}d\theta$$
$$=9\int\sin^2\theta d\theta$$
$$=\frac{9\theta}{2} - \frac{9\sin2\theta}{4}+ C$$

This is where I'm stuck.

---

**The expected result**
$$\frac{(\sqrt{9-x^2})^3}{3}-9\sqrt{9-x^2}+C$$

---

**Question**

What errors have I done, or what am I missing ?

Please don't just throw the answer with fixed solving, I'd like to have some explanation so I don't reproduce errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be $$=\int\frac{27\sin^{\color{red}2} \theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{9-9\sin^2\theta}}d\theta$$
Then,
notice that the integral becomes$$9\int \sin^{2} \theta\  d\theta$$
You've got it in terms of theta, so convert it back to x. Since
$$x = 3\sin\theta$$ Theta is $$arcsin(\frac{x}{3}) =\theta$$
Substitute this and manipulate.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the correct result. Would you mind checking my edit ? Upvoted.

Comment: @MathLearner Do that, and check here for ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: @MathLearner You can see that $\cos(\arcsin(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ , now you know that you've to expand the second term you've got with a trig identity, and substitute that formula I just mentioned earlier in this comment: sin(2x)=2sin(x)cos(x)

Comment: how is cos(arcsin(x)) useful for me ? I end up with $$\frac{9(arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))}{2} - \frac{9\sin(\arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))}{4}$$

which simplify to

$$\frac{9(arcsin(\frac{x}{3}))}{2} - \frac{4x}{3}$$

Comment: $9\sin(2\theta)=18\sin\theta\cos\theta$

Comment: @MathLearner You missed the cos(x) term.

Comment: now I end up with

$$\frac{9\theta}{2} - \frac{18x\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$$

any idea why ? I know that I can simplify $\frac{18}{3}$ but I wanted to keep it so it is easier for you to see where I've used the $$18\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

Comment: Check your working and you calculations. Even the previous comment of yours had an arithmetic mistake. I've an exam.. So will chat in 7 hours or so.

Comment: Alright, thanks for you help. I will accept the answer if I figure out the problem, else I will comment and wait/hope a feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the integral is $$9\int \sin^{\color{red}2} \theta\  d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the correct result. Would you mind checking my edit ? Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2=9\sin^2\theta\neq 9\sin \theta$$ in your substitution.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the correct result. Would you mind checking my edit ? Upvoted.

Comment: @MathLearner Note that you have to rewrite $\theta$ in terms of $x$.